# Magento 1.9 - doesn't show my customer custom image attribute on the frontend

Tags: magento-1.9

Starting at the beginning

I managed to include a custom attribute so that I could enter an image in my database at the moment when some user register. At first it kept this attribute without problem. But after saving it, it does not show it to me in the customer's frontend, even though it is well saved and the data is correct. Besides that it doesn't save it when editing it, only the first time when the user registers.

The code displayed in the frontend:

```
<div class="show-logo">

        <label for="Your Logo"><?php echo $this->__('Your Logo') ?></label>
        <br />
        <div style="width: 200px; height: 150px; background: no-repeat center center url(file: <?php echo $this->__('http://'),$host,'/media/customer',$this->escapeHtml($this->getCustomer()->getLogotype()) ?> ); background-size:cover;" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Your Logo'); ?>" class="logo-company">

        </div>

</div>
```

where `$host` is take it before from the command `$host= $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];`

The properties of the attribute:

```
$this->addAttribute('customer', 'logotype', array(
    'type'    => 'varchar',
    'input'   => 'file',
    'label'     => 'Your Logo',
    'position'  => 10,
    'required'  => false,
    'is_system' => 0,
    'visible'   => true,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'source'    => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table', 
));
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'logotype');
$attribute->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'checkout_register',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_edit',
));
$attribute->setData('is_user_defined', 0);
$attribute->save();
?>
```

Change the permissions of the folder, so that it allows me to see it without problem and the pointer is correct, but nothing.

It does not show the logotype and I want to display at the moment of the customer login on their account.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I had an answer after trying some methods.

In my case, I was editing the `edit.phtml` file to show the company logo also when editing it, but that's where it is not displayed. When I edited directly on `dashboard.phtml` the logo show out without problem. My question is, why doesn't it shows out there? At least that was my solution.

Answer (score 0):

it seems your attributeCode to display the customer logo is wrong than the one used.

It should be

> $this->getCustomer()->getLogotype()

not

> $this->getCustomer()->getLogotipo()

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad there, but still doesn't work for some weird reason...